# Subclass communicate with Root Class

Tags: ios, delegates, objective-c-category

I am trying to make a dynamic Registration Form Structure. So based on the providing xml or data, it will generate a dynamic form. Here is the screen shot of my Class hierarchies.

[image]

Here, Form class is the Base Class. Depending on the provided data, it will generate how many pages of forms needs to be created. Every page can have one table but one or more Groups (actually section view). Every group has custom fields and the custom fields can contains special TextFeild or Dropdown field or ImageField.

Here is the generated form screen:

[image]

The problem I am facing now is: My Page.m class contains the table view delegate methods and I need to fire an Event from my CF_Fields class. For example: CFImageView contains the ImagePickerController Delegate methods. When the image is picked from library, then I need to expand the table view cell height. But I don't have that event access from CFImageView class.

The class hierarchies are:
"Form" Contains "Page" classes (Table Logic is here)
"Page" Contains "Group" classes
"Group" Contains "CustomFeild" classes
"CustomFeild" Contains "FieldView" classes
"FieldView" Contains "CFTextField" or "CFDropdown" or "CFImageView" classes

I need to fire an event from the bottom classes in Page class.

Do I need to inherit all of my classes, or do I need to use delegate or should I maintain categories ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I communicated with the following way. But I don't know is it the right way or not!

```
-(void)pageViewUpdate
{
    BOOL found = FALSE;
    UIView *currentSuperView = self;

    while (!found) {
        if ([[currentSuperView superview] isKindOfClass:[CustomField class]]) {
            CustomField *customField = (CustomField *)[currentSuperView superview];
            customField.height = CUSTOM_FIELD_IMAGE_HEIGHT+CUSTOM_FIELD_IMAGE_VIEW_CELL_HEIGHT_PADDING;
        }

        if([[currentSuperView superview] isKindOfClass:[Page class]])
        {
            found = TRUE;
            Page *page = (Page *)[currentSuperView superview];
            [page updateTableView];
        }

        currentSuperView = [currentSuperView superview];
    }
}
```

I am searching for my desired superview class then access the necessary properties.